# ASP.NET MVC forms authentication equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

when I was writing ASP.NET applications I used the Forms Authentication with my custom login page, like so:

Once login is a success I checked him as authenticated:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userId.ToString(), true);
```

In order to check if a user is logged in, I had a class that inherited from a base page and all pages inherited from it, which contained a method that returned a bool after checking if the user is authenticated, with the following command:

```
return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Now, I'm doing an ASP.NET MVC application, and was wondering what is the best was to do that on MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok MVC is very simple and similar

for your question you can use like .......

in your controller

public ActionResult LogOn()

```
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userInfo = new UserInfo()
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Password = model.Password,
            };

            var service = new CSVService();
            if(service.ValidateUser(userInfo))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. does it have some kind of attribute that can be placed before ActionResult so only allowed users can view it?

Comment: ok for that you can use permission table and according to permission and role rights you can apply permission to particular user

Answer (score 1):

The best way to authenticate website / web-application is using the Membership which is provided by Microsoft built in for Easy-ness .

From this you can do following things(features)

- it maintains Log-in status (you don't have to bother about Authentication).
- It allows to provide Roles & Users and Assigning permission who can see which page 
           (Page Restriction)
- It provides built-in Stored Procedures and UI tools like Log-in, Log-out,user,Password Recovery, Etc elements. & Highly secure (Hack-Proof)

for more info:

[Walk through Membership (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I saw a tutorial on youtube about that - does it create another database?

Comment: Yes, but it is totally encrypted and you can only call the predefined stored procedures, For restricting the pages for particular user / particular browser you need to use administrative tools from Project Tab->ASP.NET Configurations  (this admin tools modifies the web.config file ) which will provides & sets permissions.